# FLT Finite Solution Sets for Non-Integer Exponent

Tags: number-theory

We all know that the equations $$ x^n + y^n = z^n\,\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,\, \gcd (x,y,z)=1$$ have no positive integer solutions for $n>2$.
We also know that for $n=1$ and $n=2$, the number of solutions is infinite.
So with $n$ a fixed positive integer, the size of the solution set is either zero or infinite.

I am interested in how these results generalise when $n$ is a positive real number ($x, y, z$ are positive integers with $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$ throughout this question).
I already understand that the set of possible values of $n$ for which a solution exists is dense in $[0, \infty)$ so please don't speak to that.
In particular, I'm interested in the following questions:

> **1.** For what values $n \in \mathbb{R}^+$ is the size of the solution set to the above equation positive and finite?
> **2.** Given $N \in \mathbb{N}$, does there always exists some $n \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that the number of integer solutions to the above equation is $N$?